# phpunit depends не передает окружение

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

Есть следующий тест. На моем компьютере тест отрабатывает ОК. На компьютере другого разработчика методе `testRoleDictFields`, выдает ошибку:

> *Argument #2 (No Value) of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertObjectHasAttribute() must be a object*

Т.е. в него не передается `$dict`. Настройки и версии php, PHPUnit, конфиг-файла и бутстрапа на обоих компьютерах идентичные. Что я мог еще упустить?

```
    class RolesDictTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
       public function testRoleDictGetById()
       {
            $dict = Dicts\Role::getByID(330);
            $this->assertInstanceOf(Dicts\Role::class, $dict);

            return $dict;
       }

       /**
        * @depends testRoleDictGetById
        *
        * @param $dict Dicts\Role
        */
       public function testRoleDictFields($dict)
       {
           $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('id', $dict, 'Field "id" not defined');
           $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('code', $dict, 'Field "code" not defined');
           $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('name', $dict, 'Field "name" not defined');
           $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('active', $dict, 'Field "active" not defined');
           $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('sort', $dict, 'Field "sort" not defined');
       }
    }
```

**UPD.** Попробовал переписать тест с использованием провайдера.

Теперь тест выглядит так:

```
class RolesDictTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider rolesIdProvider
     *
     * @param $dict Dicts\Role
     */
    public function testRoleDictClass($dict)
    {
        $this->assertInstanceOf(Dicts\Role::class, $dict);
    }

    /**
     * @dataProvider rolesIdProvider
     * @depends      testRoleDictClass
     *
     * @param $dict Dicts\Role
     */
    public function testRoleDictFields($dict)
    {
        $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('id', $dict, 'Field "id" not defined');
        $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('code', $dict, 'Field "code" not defined');
        $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('name', $dict, 'Field "name" not defined');
        $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('active', $dict, 'Field "active" not defined');
        $this->assertObjectHasAttribute('sort', $dict, 'Field "sort" not defined');
    }

    public function rolesIdProvider()
    {
        return [
            'with ID#330' => [Dicts\Role::getByID(330)],
            'with ID#331' => [Dicts\Role::getByID(331)],
            'with ID#333' => [Dicts\Role::getByID(333)],
        ];
    }
}
```

Результат тот же. На моём компьютере всё ОК. На другом `testRoleDictFields` не получает данные на вход.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На проблемном компьютере был включен OpCache. Отключение решило проблему

Answer (score 2):

Он и не должен. `@Depends` - это не указание на создающий данные метод, это указание на то, что аннотированный тест должен прогоняться после указанного в `@Depends`, e.g. если тестируется отдельный компонент и вся система целиком, то второй тест указывает зависимость от первого через `@Depends`, чтобы в случае провала первого теста не гонять второй, который тоже автоматом провалиться.

Очевидно, вы ищете [data provider](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers).

Comment: Из мануала @depends "passed the result of that depended-upon test as its argument" т.е. передает результат выполнения продюсера как аргумент для консьюмера. (https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.examples.StackTest2.php) И, как упомянуто, на моём компе данный тест отрабатывает полностью.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov а я вам про то, что не надо использовать менеджмент зависимостей для передачи данных. Касательно конкретного кейса - очевидно, версии все-таки не совпадают, возможно, по каким-то причинам другая версия phpunit загружается раньше композера, через include path или еще как.

Comment: "толи лыжи не едут..." в общем переделал тест на использование провайдера. Результат тот же. На моём компе тест отрабатывается, а на другом данные на вход не передаются. Куда теперь копать не представляю

Comment: @DmitryKozlov проверьте еще раз, откуда грузится phpunit, если из vendor и в composer.lock все совпадает - пишите issue мейнтейнеру.

Comment: Зло найдено. У "жертвы" был включен OpCache